# Doing Group By and Sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum one column while grouping another column.  SQL consistently
gives me two separate rows.

Following is my script and my results:

```
Select A.client, A.store, A.Type as 'Ticket Type', A.[bizdate] as 'DATE',     
sum(cast(round(c.[Amount2],2) as decimal (20,0))) 'QTY', c.SKU, c.[DESC], 
sum(cast(round(c.[Amount1],2)as decimal(20,2))) as 'Total'


From Mydatabase A inner join mydatabase.dbo.TicketHeader B on A.    
[ticket] = b.[ticket] and a.[yyyymmdd] = b.[yyyymmdd]
inner join mydatabase.dbo.ticketdetail C on C.[ticketheaderid]  =   
b.[id] and c.[class] = a.[class]

where  
A.Store = @store
and a.yyyymmdd = @yyyymmdd
and c.class <> 'balance'
and c.Subtype <> 'cancelled'
and a.type NOT IN    
('SKU','Total','CASH','CHANGE','NA','TAX1','TAX2','TAX3','TAX4','CHARGE',     
'Delivery Service', 'Tip')
and c.[DESC] <> 'NA'
and c.sku = '300129'

group by c.sku, c.[DESC],a.store, a.type, a.bizdate, a.client, c.[Amount2],    
c.[Amount1]  
order by [ticket type]

client, Store TicketType         date       qty   SKU    Description  Amount
1      2404  CURBSIDE / TO GO   20170214    1   300129  Beef TACO    2.00
1      2404  DINE IN            20170214    1   300129  Beef TACO    2.00
1      2404  DINE IN            20170214    2   300129  Beef TACO    4.00
1      2404  FOODSBY            20170214    2   300129  Beef TACO    4.00
```

I am trying to group the DINE IN  Beef TACO to one line while summing the
amount.

Comment: Take the Amount1 and Amount2 out of your group by. You are using those as your aggregate, putting them in the group by is counterproductive.

Comment: And why oh why are you storing dates as integers or varchar?

Comment: When I pull them out, it says it needs to be in the group by.  Storing dates as varchar...that is probably my issue isn't it?

Comment: changed date to a char...took out amount1 and amount2...it worked!  Thanks Sean Lange!

Comment: Changing your date to a char is changing one bad decision with another. Dates should be using the date or datetime datatypes.

Comment: Understood..but in this database, all other tables have the data as a char...has been like it for over 13 years....so want to stay consistent.  Did realize I had set as a varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several design and code issues here. Things like Amount1 and Amount2 are an indication of possible poor normalization. And aliases A, B, C is a bad habit as it makes maintenance way more difficult than it should be.

- [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

That aside your code is a mess from a formatting perspective to the point it is painful to work with. Add some white space and get your grouping situated and this should work fine.

```
Select A.client
    , A.store
    , A.Type as 'Ticket Type'
    , A.[bizdate] as 'DATE'
    , sum(cast(round(c.[Amount2],2) as decimal (20,0))) 'QTY'
    , c.SKU
    , c.[DESC]
    , sum(cast(round(c.[Amount1],2)as decimal(20,2))) as 'Total'
From Mydatabase A 
inner join mydatabase.dbo.TicketHeader B on A.[ticket] = b.[ticket] 
                                        and a.[yyyymmdd] = b.[yyyymmdd]
inner join mydatabase.dbo.ticketdetail C on C.[ticketheaderid] = b.[id] and c.[class] = a.[class]
where  
    A.Store = @store
    and a.yyyymmdd = @yyyymmdd
    and c.class <> 'balance'
    and c.Subtype <> 'cancelled'
    and a.type NOT IN    
    (
        'SKU','Total','CASH','CHANGE','NA','TAX1','TAX2','TAX3','TAX4','CHARGE','Delivery Service', 'Tip'
    )
    and c.[DESC] <> 'NA'
    and c.sku = '300129'
group by A.client
    , A.store
    , A.Type 
    , A.[bizdate] 
    , c.SKU
    , c.[DESC]
order by [ticket type]
```